# Addition program in Drools

Tags: drools

just out of curiosity i am trying to write a very simple rule in Drools of addition.(I know its not a very mature thing, but still...) 
    But getting error that $firstNum and $secondNum can't be assign to a variable. help me out...

```
rule "Addition rule"
    when
        act : CalcOperation(CalcOperation.ADD,  $firstNum : firstNum, $secondNum : secondNum)
    then
        $out : $firstNum + $secondNum;;
        //logger.info("Result of addition is : "+$out);
end

...............................................................................

Here is the CalcOperation class.

public class CalcOperation {
    Double firstNum;
    Double secondNum;
    public static  Boolean ADD;
    public static  Boolean SUB;
    public static  Boolean MUL;
    public static  Boolean DIV;

    public CalcOperation(Boolean operation, Double m, Double n){
        this.firstNum = m;
        this.secondNum = n;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dig more into Java, and a lot more into Drools documentation.

A static variable isn't useful in the context you are using it. If you want to have separate objects for addition, subtraction etc. you could subclass Operation. Instance variables should be private, and at least have a getter.

In a rule, you cannot bind a variable (`$firstNum` etc.) to a field unless it has a proper getter (or is public - not recommended).

The then-part or consequence must be written in Java. `$out : $firstNum + $secondNum;;` is *not* a valid Java statement.

Here's a Java class:

```
public enum Operator { ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV };

public class Operation {
    private double op1;
    private double op2;
    private Operator op;
    public Operation( Operator op, double op1, double op2 ){
        this.op = op;
        //...
    }
    public Operator getOp(){ return op; }
    //...
}
```

And here's the rule:

```
rule "exec op"
when
    $op: Operation( $op: Operator.ADD, $op1: op1, $op2: op2 )
then
    System.out.writeln( "result: " + ($op1 + $op2) );
end
```